# Warning when compiling, with a program that 'waits/delays'

Tags: c, warnings, sleep

I'm attempting to prompt the user to input the amount of time they want the program to wait. However, when I compile the program, it produces the forllowing warning:

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

The warnings references the following line:

```
y = sleeptime;
```

I don't quite understand this as there aren't any pointers in my program.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int sleeptime(void)
{
    int x;
    x = 0;
    printf("How long would you like to wait?\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    int y;    
    y = 0;
    y = sleeptime;
    sleep(y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you *call* functions in C? Perhaps you need a couple of [good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read?

Comment: ah i just realised the mistake. Yes i definitely could build my foundations better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just Change

```
y = sleeptime;
```

to

```
y = sleeptime();
```